# Acquire "signature" permissionlevel on Android

Tags: android, permissions

I'm building an Android app, and one of the permission I need is defined as:

```
android:protectionLevel="signature|system|development"
```

How do I get the signature protection level? Do I need to sign my application somehow?

Do I need to sign it with OEM ? (Samsung\HTC\LG)?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  There may be another approach.

Comment: I'm trying to read logcat file through my application.
this requires the permission android.permission.READ_LOGS
which have changed recently the protection level to be as I described above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`signature` means that to be able to get access to the resource, your app have to be signed with the same certificate that the holder of the permission. If this is not your app you are trying to connect to, then you basically are out of luck. If that's system one then you are out of luck even more, [This is documented here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html):

> **"signature"**
>
> A permission that the system grants only if the
> requesting application is signed with the same certificate as the
> application that declared the permission. If the certificates match,
> the system automatically grants the permission without notifying the
> user or asking for the user's explicit approval.

**EDIT**

> Im trying to read logcat file through my application. this requires
> the permission android.permission.READ_LOGS

You cannot access logs on stock ROM that are not created by your application. That's introduced for security reasons, so would not make sense to let you get it just because you need it. If you build own ROM, then you can have it, but then you should know this already.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
But just to be clear:
If I'm signing my APK with Samsung (for example) is it possible to sign it with LG and HTC later as well ?
from what i understood I send the OEM an apk and they return a signed one.

Comment: You cannot have more than one signature for single apk.

Comment: Marcin: but the permission level says signature|system|development
which means i need to gain at least one of those.
You claim that even if i gain the signature permission level i still wouldnt be able to reat them ?

Comment: not sure what "reat" mean. But "|" stands for OR, so once you can have any of these three, you got access.