# android GET_TASKS Permission Deprecated

Tags: android, android-intent, task, activity-manager

I've used GET_TASKS permission in my app in order to get previous intent.

```
private Intent getPreviousIntent(Intent newIntent) {
    final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> recentTaskInfos = am.getRecentTasks(1024,0);
    String myPkgNm = getPackageName();

    if (!recentTaskInfos.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo recentTaskInfo;
        for (int i = 0; i < recentTaskInfos.size(); i++) {
            recentTaskInfo = recentTaskInfos.get(i);
            if (recentTaskInfo.baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName().equals(myPkgNm)) {
                newIntent = recentTaskInfo.baseIntent;
                newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            }
        }
    }
    return newIntent;
}
```

In api level 21 *getAppTasks* is added instead of *getRecentTasks*.It is ok but the question is that how can i get previous intent lower than api level 21? Please help me in order to solve this issue?

Comment: You can check the API Level on running device and use for lower getAppTasks...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093365/how-can-i-check-the-system-version-of-android

Comment: No problem to check API level, but *getAppTasks* doesn't work lower than api level 21. The problem is that how i can get previous intent for example android 4 without using *getRecentTasks*?

Comment: Yes, but You can do an if else statement. If Your project targeting API Level 21, and minimum a lower level, You can check by if/else which API the device has and then use the method You need in that if/else....You need an example?

Comment: Please read the question again. if u did please help how can i get previous intent from my app? I don't wanna use deprecated methods

Comment: I read the question correctly :) ....but You have to use deprecated methods if You developing on minSDK lower than Your target.....that´s the only way...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GET\_TASKS Permission Deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27974583/get-tasks-permission-deprecated)