# My Custom BroadcastReceiver is not working above API level 16

Tags: android

I'm doing my college project which was Parental Control app. In that I'm creating a Custom Receiver. I'm  tested that app in jelly bean,kitkat,lollipop, marshmallow, naughat ,oreo. But it only works in jelly bean and kitkat. I'm tried reading all solutions in stackoverflow. Please give solution for me!

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.nizam.training.parentalcontrol">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />


<application
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/m"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@mipmap/ico"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service
        android:name=".BlockService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"/>

    <activity android:name=".AppSettingActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BlockActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="Login"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SignupActivity"
        android:label="Create Pin"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TaskList"
        android:label="Tasks"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission=""
        tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="StartupReceiver_Manual_Start" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".CheckRunningApplicationReceiver" />
</application></manifest>
```

Calling broabcast in TaskListActivity.java

```
getApplicationContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent("StartupReceiver_Manual_Start"))
```

LogCat

http://mnktalktech.blogspot.com/2019/02/logcat-for-parentalcontrol.html

Comment: If you are running on emulator, please check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966496 .

Comment: @amitava I installed this app using apk file, In his device also my Custom BroadcastReceiver not working.

Comment: Please make android:exported="false" and remove tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver" and try.

Comment: @amitava I have tried it also. And also I have tried many ways but no solution found.

Comment: I work with Nougat and Oreo(Go), and I used BroadcastReceiver. My code is little different. Can I post that as answer?

Comment: @amitava Thank you for your interest. Please post that answer.

Comment: Just before doing that let me confirm one more thing. Would you also remove android:permission=""  and check. Finally what I want is                           
 <receiver
            android:name="..MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

Comment: I posted this as answer as hardly it is recognisable here.

Answer (score 0):

I found this; it might be part of the issue.  Are you getting any errors?

[GET_TASKS Permission Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27974583/get-tasks-permission-deprecated)

Comment: I have removed GET_TASKS and run the app but same problem exists.

Comment: Error not occured in API level 16. But in later API levels  I can see too many Red lines in Logcat but I can't understand it.

Comment: Can you put that Logcat messages in the code in your question?

Comment: @amitava Kk I will include logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this.

```
<receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="StartupReceiver_Manual_Start"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a week in this issue I have found solution for this.
What I put before (which is not working)...

```
getApplicationContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent("StartupReceiver_Manual_Start"))
```

Now I just changed.

```
MyReceiver mr=new MyReceiver();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("StarctupReceiver_Manual_Start");
registerReceiver(mr,intentFilter);
getBaseContext().getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("StarctupReceiver_Manual_Start"));
```

I don't know why it is working but it works.If anyone know the reason please comment. Thanks for all who tried to solve this issue.